# How can we use multiple count and multiple group by in SQL at the same time?

Tags: sql, count, group-by

So i have this table

```
             `gender  country  age  name  ID
              male    VietNam  20   Q     890 
              female  China    30   K     209
              female  Japan    25   O     302
              female  VietNam  20   L     203
              male    China    20   E     504`
```

i want to make a query which can list the number of people who has the same gender,same country and same age in individual by count and group by like this

`Select gender,COUNT(*) from Employee Group BY gender
 Select country,COUNT(*) from Employee Group BY country
 Select age,COUNT(*) from Employee Group BY age`

Is there any way to make it in just one select ?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: What DBMS are you using?MySQL, Sql Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc..?

Comment: SQL server management studio

Answer (score 2):

You could UNION to get these results in separate records of your result set:

```
 Select 'Gender' as GroupByType, gender as GroupByValue ,COUNT(*) from Employee Group BY gender
 UNION ALL
 Select 'Country', country,COUNT(*) from Employee Group BY country
 UNION ALL
 Select 'Age', age,COUNT(*) from Employee Group BY age
```

Comment: The second select needs a comma between 'Country' and country ;)

Comment: I have this error when i execute the query: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'male' to data type int.Is there any way to fix it? thanks for your help

Comment: Try CAST(age as VARCHAR(20)) in the last query and see if that makes it happy.

Comment: the last query will look like this ?                                                                 `Select 'Age', age,COUNT(*) from Employee Group BY age,CAST(age as VARCHAR(20))`

Comment: My apologies for not getting back right away. The last query will look like `SELECT 'Age', CAST(age as VARCHAR(20)), Count(*) from Employee GROUP BY age`. The reason we want to cast that is that your DB will try to cast all of the records in that field to an integer otherwise, which is what is causing the error you are getting. A Union stacks the results of each of the query, so each field in a UNION has to be of the same `type`. So here we are just forcing our number to text so it foots with the other queries.

Answer (score 2):

If your RDBMS supports it...  [SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427(v=sql.105).aspx), [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/aggreg.htm) and others do.... not sure what you're using.

`Group by Grouping sets`

```
Select count(*), gender, country, age 
from employee 
group by grouping sets ((gender), (country), (age ))
```

and depending on the type of output you're looking for... this will result in 4 columns a count, gender, country, and age columns where 2 of the 4 columns will always be null.

it will result in a similar output to JNevill's except no groupbyType, instead there's a separate column for each value in the `group by`